# Can someone help me with this AHK Script

Tags: autohotkey

I want this Autohotkey script to  press the spacebar automatically with a toggle option so i dont have to hold the spacebar all the time. The toggle  key  should be the middle mouse button. Could you  please write  it correctly  for  me?  Because  the toggle part I found  doesn't   seem to work. Thanks  in advance  CptPrice :D

```
Main script:
*~$Space::
Sleep 100
Loop
{
GetKeyState, SpaceState, Space, P
If SpaceState = U
break
Sleep 5
Send, {Blind}{Space}
}

Toggle-part:

#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2   

MButton::
if (toggle := !toggle) {
    ; on
} else {
    ; off
}
return
```

Answer (score 2):

```
toggle := false
return

MButton:: toggle := !toggle

#If toggle

#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

*~$Space::
Sleep 100
Loop 
{
Sleep 5
Send, {Blind}{Space}
    if (!toggle)        ; Press MButton to break
        break
}
return

#If
```

Comment: thank  you  very much   now  i  can  bhop like  a  god without  holding  the  space bar hehehehhehe  :DD

Comment: He got two downvotes for no reason. What do you think he feels about SO community? "What a bunch of gentlemen"? I don't think so. He is already too kind to SO. Your answer worked, so I upvoted you.